# Superuser Issue in ruby kubuntu

Tags: ruby, eclipse, root, ubuntu

I have installed ruby and gems with sudo,

Whenever I run the script, I have to do it with sudo or else I will get this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'from Login.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I am planning to use eclipse IDE, so--if I do run the script in eclipse--I get the same problem

Could someone help me in running ruby script as superuser in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the access permissions for needed gem.

`sudo chmod 644 filename`

To know the full path:

`gem which gemname`

Comment: I Tried changing the access permissions, but din work, getting same problem

Comment: Check access permissions to all folders in path?